# Where can I find a Google Chrome OS ISO image?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, google-chrome-os

Where can I get a Google Chrome OS .ISO file? I know I could install ubuntu and build from source but I don't want to do that. Are there any ISO's available?

Comment: I have started a bounty to this question because I **really need** an iso to use on my old computer that can't boot from USB.

Comment: I know you want Google Chrome, but in reference to your previous comment, you might try Ubuntu or Damn Small Linux (just to get your machine up and running).

Answer (score 6):

[Hexxeh’s Chromium builds](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) are supposedly pretty popular (and I’ve liked the ones I’ve tried). They host torrent to ISOs, as well as IMG files and VirtualBox-ready archives.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to a virtualbox image of Chrome OS.  I don't believe there is an installer for *real* hardware yet.

http://geeklad.com/download-the-google-chrome-os-virtual-machine

Comment: There's perhaps not a real "installer", but Chromium can certainly be run on real hardware (via USB or LiveCD).

Answer (score 2):

You can run Chrome from a [USB flash drive](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-google-chrome-os-and-run-on-a-real-computer/). It's not technically an ISO, but it's pretty close.

Comment: this is more appropriate to post as a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question.  once you get to 50 rep you'll see the gray "add comment" links below other posts.

Comment: I think it's pretty close to an answer. Moreover, answering questions is the best way to build up rep anyway.

Comment: This is the VM in Kevin's answer, repackaged by its author.

Answer (score 0):

A [VMWare image](https://web.archive.org/web/20131117213156/http://gdgt.com/google/chrome-os/download/)(vmdk) is available. you can even check the related videos, How's to at [this site.](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Chrome OS ISO image download link, and methods on how to install Chrome OS on windows 7 or Mac OS X:

https://www.trickyways.com/2009/11/how-to-run-chrome-os-in-windows-7/

https://www.trickyways.com/2009/12/how-to-install-chrome-os-in-mac-os-x/